# How do I write methods that insert rspec examples?

Tags: ruby, rspec, helpermethods

In a bunch of rspec rails unit specifications I do something like:

```
describe Foo do
  [:bar, :baz].each do |a|
    it "should have many #{a}" do
      Foo.should have_many(a)
    end
  end
end
```

For cleaner code I'd rather do something like:

```
describe Foo do
  spec_has_many Foo, :bar, :baz
end
```

So how do I write a helper method like `spec_has_many()` for inserting DSL code like rspec's `it()` method? If it were for an ordinary instance method I'd do something like:

```
def spec_has_many(model, *args)
  args.each do |a|
    define_method("it_should_have_many_#{a}") do
      model.should have_many(a)
    end
  end
end
```

What would be the equivalent for defining rspec examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, this took some messing around, but I think I got it working. It's a bit of metaprogramming hackery, and I personally would just use the first thing you described, but it's what you wanted :P

```
module ExampleMacros
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # This will be available as a "Class Macro" in the included class
    def should_have_many(*args)
      args.each do |a|
        # Runs the 'it' block in the context of the current instance
        instance_eval do
          # This is just normal RSpec code at this point
          it "should have_many #{a.to_s}" do
            subject.should have_many(a)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

describe Foo do
  # Include the module which will define the should_have_many method
  # Can be done automatically in RSpec configuration (see below)
  include ExampleMacros

  # This may or may not be required, but the should_have_many method expects
  # subject to be defined (which it is by default, but this just makes sure
  # it's what we expect)
  subject { Foo }

  # And off we go. Note that you don't need to pass it a model
  should_have_many :a, :b
end
```

My specs fail because Foo doesn't have a `has_many?` method, but both tests run, so it should work.

You can define (and rename) the ExampleMacros module in your `spec_helper.rb` file and it will be available for inclusion. You want to call `include ExampleMacros` in your `describe` blocks (and not any others).

To make all of your specs include the module automatically, configure RSpec like so:

```
# RSpec 2.0.0
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include ExampleMacros
end
```